# How to make a form with ChoiceType linked with PHP enum

Tags: symfony, radio-button, symfony-forms, symfony5

I'm beginner in Symfony, I have a problem when I submit my form :

---

First, I created and Enum called Color:

```
enum Color: string
{
    case Red = "R";
    case Blue = "B";
    case Green = "G";
    case Yellow = "Y";
}
```

Then, I have an entity Car :

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CarRepository::class)]
class Car
{
    ...

    #[ORM\Column(type: "string", nullable: true, enumType: Color::class)]
    private Color $color;

    public function getColor(): Color
    {
       return $this->color;
    }

    public function setColor(Color $color): void
    {
        $this->color= $color;
    }

    ...
}
```

So I created a Form of Car entity with the command

> php bin/console make:form

And I want to have the field 'color' with radio buttons, so my form is like this :

```
->add('color', ChoiceType::class, [
   'expanded' => true
])
```

In the form view I need the names of enum, but for database storage I just want to have the values of enum.

How can I do that ?

Thanks to read me.
Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

Please see documentation [Symfony Enum Type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/enum.html)

you can use like this way

```
$builder->add('color', EnumType::class, ['class' => Color::class]);
```

Comment: My bad, my research was limited to "RadioType" instead "EnumType"

Comment: If this is helpful to you then please accept this answer so in the future this is helpful to others

Comment: Miss me 4 reputation points